# Problems instaling Ubuntu - stuck loading 'try without installing'

Tags: boot, live-usb, freeze

I was a Windows 10 user, and got tired of it, and decided to install Linux. I tried Linux Mint, but I had some problems.

So I created an Ubuntu USB boot drive, and tried to install Ubuntu that way.

- I changed the BIOS to use the USB to load, and it got into the Ubuntu installation menu
- I selected the language, and after that i choose to "try Ubuntu without installing", but the Ubuntu logo appeared, and it froze right after that.
- I tried it several times, and mounted the USB several times as well, but nothing worked so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is this question tagged playonlinux?